# error in citing references

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Please can someone help me figure why my Tex does not run whenever I try cite the references. Without reference citing, my whole Tex file will build(run).

Here is the latex file

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p, review,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[running]{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.8cm}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Cramer's rule was named after a Swiss mathematician Gabriel Cramer
(1704-1752) \cite{Cramer}. Historically, an Italian mathematician
Gerolamo Cardano gave a rule called \textit{regula de modo}- mother of rules, in his ``\textit{ars magna''}. Though his
methods were practically based on $2\times 2$ resultants.  \cite{Gardano}.

\noindent \textbf{References}
\bibliography{ok}
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\end{document}
```

and here is the bibtex file

```
@book{cramer1750introduction,
  title={Introduction a l'analyse des lignes courbes algebriques par Gabriel Cramer...},
  author={Cramer and Gabriel and Cramer fr{\`e}res \& Philibert and Claude},
  year={1750},
  publisher={chez les freres Cramer \& Cl. Philibert}
}


@article{cardano1968ars,
  title={Ars magna (1545)},
  author={Cardano, Girolamo and Spon, C},
  journal={Opera Omnia},
  volume={4},
  pages={221--302},
  year={1968}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code features two `\cite` instructions: `\cite{Cramer}` and `\cite{Gardano}`. The two entries in the bib file, though, have the following keys: `cramer1750introduction` and `cardano1968ars`. This cannot possibly go well. You need to change either the arguments of the `\cite` instructions or the keys of the bibliographic entries. Then re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Your preamble features an additional problem: You load both the `cite` package (twice actually! -- why?) and the `natbib` package. You should load one or the other citation management package, *but not both*. I suggest you drop the `cite` package and load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`.

Fixing up the *contents* of the bib file (I consulted Google Books) and stripping the preamble down to a bare minimum yields the following compilable code.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ok.bib}
@book{Cramer,
  title    = {Introduction {\`a} L'Analyse des Lignes Courbes Alg{\'e}briques},
  author   = {Cramer, Gabriel},
  year     = {1750},
  publisher= {Fr{\`e}res Cramer \& Cl.\ Philibert},
  address  = {Geneva},
}
@incollection{Cardano,
  title    = {{Ars Magna} (1545)},
  author   = {Cardano, Girolamo},
  editor   = {Sponi, Charles},
  booktitle= {Opera Omnia},
  volume   = {4},
  pages    = {221--302},
  year     = {1663},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[preprint,3p,review,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Cramer's Rule is named after the Swiss mathematician Gabriel Cramer (1704--1752), who
hinted that resultants (determinants) might be useful in analytical geometry~\cite{Cramer}. 
Earlier, the Italian mathematician Gerolamo Cardano, in 1545, gave a rule for solving a 
system of two linear equations which he called \textit{regula de modo}---mother of 
rules---in his \textit{Ars Magna}. However, his methods were in practice based on 
$2\times2$ resultants. The rule later gave what we essentially know as Cramer's 
Rule~\cite{Cardano}.

\bigskip\noindent 
\textbf{References}
\bibliography{ok}
\end{document}
```